# How to query all posts in CPT + only posts with custom tax in another CPT?

Tags: wp-query

I have 2 post types.
Both use the same custom taxonomy.
How can I create a query that will display;

1. All posts of CPT1, and
2. All posts of CPT2 that have a taxonomy.

Is this possible with a single query?

Comment: The only way to do this with a single query would be to assign a single taxonomy term to all CPT1 posts. Then you can use a taxonomy query to query those and CPT2 posts with that taxonomy.

Comment: Perfect thanks!